# Why isn't “quand” the relative pronoun for dates?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, pronoms-relatifs, origine-ou-raison

Can one ever say : “*le jour quand je suis né*” instead of “*le jour où je suis né*” (illogical)?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing illogical in ***où*** je suis né.

*Où* can be used with both space and time references and this was already the case with the latin ***[ubi](http://www.dicolatin.com/FR/LAK/0/UBI/index.htm)*** from which *où* comes from.

On the other hand, unlike Spanish (*El día **cuando** nací*) or Italian (*Il giorno **cuando** sono nato*), ***quand*** can only be used as a *conjonction de subordination*, e.g.:

> *Ma sœur avait trois ans **quand** je suis né*.

When a relative pronoun introduces a time or a location, *où* is used, thus:

> *Le jour **où** je suis né*.

Comment: Who says that I cannot use quand, which is more logical than où? I know I will be corrected but I will attack lack of logic as I wish!

Comment: @B.Scholl  If you think it is logical to use an interrogative pronoun (*quand*) in place of a relative pronoun (*où*), you may say so but it won't change the fact that *où* is the normal logical relative pronoun to express time (as Jiliagre says - Latin heritage from *ubi* which expressed both time & place).

Comment: @B.Scholl If you say it that way, you will likely be always understood. It is a common mistake made by non native speakers but the fact it is incorrect. A similar one would be using *que* instead of *dont*, e.g. *Ce que je t'ai parlé*. Most if not all languages, except possibly esperanto, aren't built from logical rules.

Answer (score 0):

**où** est un pronom relatif de lieu, secondairement de temps

voir  [le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/o%C3%B9)

alors que **quand** ne permet pas ces constructions, sauf en tant que conjonction de subordination (temporelle) : *quand il est né ...* :

*Le jour quand il est né* **est incorrect.**

*Il a crié quand il est né* **est correct.**

Comment: Your arguments are circular. Quand can be used in constructions if the speaker wishes and if he/she is understood or can explain why it is sensible to 'break the rules'.

Comment: @B.Scholl , j'ai complété les exemples, avec ce qui est incorrect ou correct. Ce n'est pas selon le souhait de celui qui parle.